# Move files to archive folder in subfolder in Powershell - add a variable to destination

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Forgive me for being new to Powershell, but I am hoping the community can help. 
I need to move files of a certain age to an archive subfolder, but I need to be able to create one script to work on multiple folders with multiple destinations. Below is the powershell script is what I am working with.

```
get-childitem -Path "c:\source" -recurse |
  where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | 
  move-item -destination "c:\source\[subfolder]\archive"
```

So there are many child folders in c:\source. All of the child folders have a folder named "archive." I want to be able to set the destination to be the source subfolder's "archive" folder:
c:\source\%variable%\archive

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$children = get-childitem -Path "c:\source" |
  where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31) -and $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}

foreach($child in $children)
{
     $childArchivePath = $child.FullName + "\archive"
     Move-Item $child -Destination $childArchivePath
}
```

Don't have a data set to play with, but you could drop this into your ISE and step through with the debugger to tinker with.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to tinker with it in ISE. So far I haven't figured out why after running the script, nothing happens.